# Passing a class instance as a parameter to one of its own functions

Tags: objective-c, function, class, methods, properties

When a class of properties *(let's call it class_X)* is being instantiated from another class, all of class_X's methods and functions are also included in every instance.

**Q1:** *Wouldn't that add substantial overheads, especially if there are multiple instances of that class?*

The class instance *(class_X)* could then be passed to other methods and functions in other classes as a parameter.

**Q2:** *Is it safe to pass it as a parameter to a C-style function (let's call it function_C) which resides in the same class (function_C resides in class_X)?*

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: *Here's some code to illustrate:***

*class_X header:*

```
    //class_X.h

    @interface class_X : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger intProp;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrProp;

    void function_C (class_X *cx);

    @end
```

*class_X implementation:*

```
    //class_X.m

    #import "class_X.h"

    @implementation class_X

    void function_C (class_X *cx)
    {
        //code...
    }

    @end
```

*instantiating class_X:*

```
    @implementation someOtherViewController

    - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        class_X *cx = [[class_X alloc] init];

        cx.intProp = 123;
        cx.arrProp = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];

        function_C (cx);   //does this not cause some sort of recursion?
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have some naming conventions: "class instances" is akin of ambiguous. There are

- instances (or instance objects) having a class.
- classes, akin of type for an instance object.
- class objects

So I assume that you want to use "instance objects of class X", when you write "class instances".

To your Q:

1. No, there is no overhead. Objective-C is a class-based programming language in contrast to JS that is prototype-based. That has the consequence that every instance has all instance methods that are declared as instance methods by the class. Therefore they are stored only a single time for all instances. The memory footprint for the methods does not depend on the number of instances are created. It is a one-timer. (The memory footprint for properties depends heavily on the number of instances.)
2. It is completely safe to pass references to instances to a function. Moreover the function can be defined everywhere. Of course, it has to see the interface of the class f the passed instance, probably via an import.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, the methods are not repeated for each instance, but the properties are; _didn't know that._ Also, you mentioned that the function can be anywhere; _even if it is in the same class? (please see my updated code example)_  And are properties very much heavier than conventional variables? Once again, thank you.

Comment: 1. It can be inside the same class, a different class or outside a class. I. e. `NSLog()` is a C function and is not inside any class. 2. Every instance var has the same memory footprint as a local var or a global var has, typically a machine word (8 Bytes). So you can calculate a circa value by: number of properties per instance × number of instances × 8 Bytes = memory footprint.

Comment: _Great!_ One last one, please. Is it true that C-style functions are not included when the class that it resides in is instantiated by another class? In my example above, even though it is placed within the class @implementation/@end,  `function_C()` will not be part of the object?

Comment: No, they are not included: There is no reason to include that function, because you can simply use it with `function_c()` without any relationship to a class. Even functions are declared inside classes, they have no relationship to the class or its instances.